# "Now Playing..." track info on blackberry smartphone

Tags: blackberry, java-me, media-player

I'm developing java-based app for Blackberry OS 7. One of the possible features can be to see the name of currently playing audio file. The question: is it possible to get this information from system using only Java API? Is it possible at all to get access to this kind of information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't suppose there is any straightforward way to get this information, at least not any that is documented. BlackBerry's Java API is somewhat silly in that sense, unfortunately.

If you want you can probably do some ad-hockery to attempt to get that info, but it won't be painless. One example can be scraping the UI elements of the "Now Playing" application that runs in the background during playback for any changes and reflecting those in your app, but then again, it won't be exactly elegant.